# Get Current GPS Location. Emulator vs Phone

Tags: android, gps

so i followed this tutorial http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/12/how-to-get-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android.html

and I successfully was able to run it on Nox emulator however I tried using it on my phone and the toast message pops up saying that "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code"

can someone explain why? I already turned on my GPS and wifi on my cellphone. maybe the permissions on my device?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android do you have on phone? If it is above 5.0, you have to call permissions like this:
`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);`

Comment: in your onCreate() method. The best way is to place it under setContentView(R/.layout.something);

Comment: in worked on my phone but tried i tried it with other devices in still didnt work. :(